# Adding object to javascript array from localstorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I am trying to add chat messages in local storage.
For this I am writing the following code:

```
var oldMessages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(self+'_'+other)) || [];
var newMsg = [{
               'from':self,
               'to':other,
               'msg':text
             }];
newMsg.push(oldMessages);
localStorage.setItem(self+'_'+other,JSON.stringify(newMsg));
```

For this I am getting the output as:

> 9015825_9032836
>   : "[  {"from":"9015825","to":"9032836","msg":"Hi\n"},  [  {"from":"9015825","to":"9032836","msg":"hello\n"},[{"from":"9015825","to":"9032836","msg":"Bbye\n"},[]]]]"

whereas I expect the output to be

> 9015825_9032836 : "[ {"from":"9015825","to":"9032836","msg":"Hi\n"}, {"from":"9015825","to":"9032836","msg":"hello\n"},{"from":"9015825","to":"9032836","msg":"Bbye\n"},]"

so that I can iterate over the objects when required.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an array (`oldMessages`) as an element of `newMsg`, you should flatten the contents of `oldMessages`.

### ES6

You can do this using the `...` ([spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)).

```
var newMsg = [{
               'from':self,
               'to':other,
               'msg':text
             },
             ...oldMessages
];
```

---

### ES5

There are, of course, many ways to do very similar things even in the older ES5 syntax.

1. [Array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_push)

   An alternative is to use a better version of [Array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_push), which concatenates the contents of oldMessages onto newMsg:

   ```
   Array.prototype.push.apply(newMsg, oldMessages);
   ```
2. [Array unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

   Because your new message is only an object, it would be better to just add the object to top of the stack.  This can be done using the [Array unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method.

   ```js
   var messages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(self + '_' + other)) || [];
   var newMessage = {
     'from': self,
     'to': other,
     'msg': text
   };
   messages.unshift(newMessage);
   localStorage.setItem(self + '_' + other, JSON.stringify(messages));
   ```

   Notice that *newMessage* is now an object, not an array and the *unshift* makes it the first element of the *messages* array.
3. [Array concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

   Similar to the spread, push, and unshift; the *concat* method creates a new array, by combining two others.  It more closely resembles the spread operator, since contents are flattened and the original arrays are not mutated.

   ```js
   var oldMessages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(self + '_' + other)) || [];
   var newMessage = [{
     'from': self,
     'to': other,
     'msg': text
   }];
   messages = newMessage.concat(oldMessages);
   localStorage.setItem(self + '_' + other, JSON.stringify(messages));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check Array [Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
var newMsg = [{
     'from':self,
     'to':other,
     'msg':text
}];

var mergedArray = newMsg.concat(oldMessages);
localStorage.setItem(self+'_'+other,JSON.stringify(mergedArray ));
```

You want to merge array of old messages with the array of `newMsg` created. Or you might just want to create an object for `newMsg` instead of   array and push that object into `oldMessages` and set it to localstorage upon stringifying.

Answer (score 0):

The oldMessages variable is also an array.
You are currently pushing the array into an array.

You can use the [Concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

or alternatively use the [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) like this:

```
var oldMessages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(self+'_'+other)) || [];
var newMsg = {
               'from':self,
               'to':other,
               'msg':text
             };
oldMessages.unshift(newMsg);
localStorage.setItem(self+'_'+other,JSON.stringify(oldMessages));
```